# Mesh editing tools disappeared

Tags: edit-mode

I'm not getting the options for vertices, edge, face selection.
[image]

Comment: Please don't scream! This object is a curve, not a mesh.

Comment: Please don't use all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting and is considered rude

Comment: Yep, what the others said. Also: you imported a DXF, right?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-a-bad-manner-to-type-in-caps

Answer (score 1):

Curve objects are different than Mesh objects as they are not constructed from vertices edges or faces, but from vectors.

You can convert the object to a mesh. In edit mode select the object and select

*Object > Convert to > Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text*

[image]